# sequelize defining a foreignKey association to another model using targetKey

Tags: sequelize.js

As per the docs, I can create a foreignKey to another model to a specific column using targetKeys option.  I am trying to do this in my below models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Booking = sequelize.define("Booking", {
    //id:           {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true},        // auto-generate
    bookingId:      {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true},
    accId:          {type:DataTypes.INTEGER},
    description:    {type:DataTypes.STRING(128)},
    amount:         {type:DataTypes.DECIMAL(15,2), allowNull:false},  // 0:prepaid, 1:postpaid
    schDate:        {type:DataTypes.DATE, allowNull:false},
    createdBy:      {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false},
    modifiedBy:     {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false}
  },
  {
    tableName: "user_bookings",
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Booking.belongsTo(models.Account, {foreignKey:'accId', targetKey:'accId'});
      }
    }
  }
);
  return Booking;
};
```

And my *other* table looks like this:

```
   module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Account = sequelize.define("Account", {
    //id:           {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true},                  // auth-generate
   userId:         {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true},
    accType:        {type:DataTypes.CHAR(1), allowNull:false},                  // 0:prepaid, 1:postpaid
    category:       {type:DataTypes.INTEGER},                                   // reserved for future use
    isDefault:      {type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue:false},               // Is this the default wallet, (if the user has many wallets. )
    balance:        {type:DataTypes.DECIMAL(15,2), defaultValue:null},
    creditLimit:    {type:DataTypes.DECIMAL(15,2), defaultValue:null},
    creditConsumed: {type:DataTypes.DECIMAL(15,2), defaultValue:null},
    createdBy:      {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false},
    modifiedBy:     {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false},
    createdAt:      {type:DataTypes.DATE, allowNull:false, get:function(){return this.getDataValue('createdAt').getTime()/1000;}},
    updatedAt:      {type:DataTypes.DATE, allowNull:false, get:function(){return this.getDataValue('updatedAt').getTime()/1000;}}
  },
  {
    tableName: "user_accounts",
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);
  return Account;
};
```

When these tables are created, I am expecting that the first model will have a foreignKey created to the 2nd one.  But that is not happening.

My user_bookings table shows as a standalone table without any references:

```
mysql> desc user_bookings;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bookingId   | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| accId       | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| amount      | decimal(15,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| schDate     | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| createdBy   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modifiedBy  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| createdAt   | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updatedAt   | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| deletedAt   | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: You pasted the definition for the Bookings twice my mistake.

Comment: Yes, a typo error. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

What *could* be wrong is your association definition:

```
Booking.belongsTo(models.Account, {foreignKey:'accId', targetKey:'accId'});
```

You don't have the attribute `accId` in your target definition, in this case `Account` table.

Take a look at the [Target keys documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#target-keys).

*Bonus:*

You don't need to declare attributes like `createdAt` and `updatedAt` when you use `timestamps: true`